# Format text field like gmail compose message area

Tags: input, formatting, textarea

How to make my text area like gmail compose message area field.
In that field the user change the **text to bold**, color,*font*, etc. and also make display the same as user typed. Like emoji plugins 
[Gmail Compose Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUK8T.png)

Is there any javascript or jquery plugin for that text formatting by the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply use ckeditor.
download the ckeditor.
extract the files 
open the folder
go to smaple folder
find the index file
aftre simply use the code in your file.
and also add the files which is used in the ckediter.